# Aristarchus calculating upper-bound ratio earth-sun:earth-moon

Tags: geometry

Aristarchus, an ancient Greek mathematician, calculated that the earth-sun distance is at least 18x and at most 20x the earth-moon distance. He was wrong due to inaccurate (measured) values which he used in his calculations. Despite that, I'm trying to go through the same calculations and see for myself how he arrived at the lower bound of 18 and the upper bound of 20.

To do so I'm using the book "Aristarchus of Samos : The Ancient Copernicus" by TL Heath (1913), which is available online, and around page 350 the original text (Greek) is being translated to English. It starts with 6 hypotheses followed by 18 propositions of which [proposition 7](https://archive.org/stream/aristarchusofsam00heat#page/376/mode/2up) details how Aristarchus arrives at his values. Using this [schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dBB1.png), the following statements are being made on page 381.

> *Then, since the angle DBE is 1/30th of a right angle, the angle BDK is also 1/30th of a right angle; therefore the circumference BK is 1/60th of the whole circle.*

Since the diameter of the inner-circle is half that of the outer circle it follows that the outer-circle is twice as big. Thus, 1/30th (3°) of a right angle (90°) of the circumference of the outer-circle is 2x the length of 1/30th (3°) of a right angle (90°) of the circumference of the the inner-circle. Hence, the circumference of BK is 1/60th of the whole circle.

At this point the accompanied schematic confuses me because ∠DBE has its vertex in B, being the center of the outer-cicle and continues along BE which is equal to the radius of the outer-circle whereas ∠BDK has its vertex in D and continues along DK which is longer than the radius of the inner-circle making me think we are comparing apples and oranges.

To have the circumference of BK be 1/60th of the outer-circle, shouldn't the vertex of ∠BDK start in the center of the inner-circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\angle BDK$ is an inscribed angle of the inner circle, then it is half the corresponding central angle. It follows that arc $BK$ of the inner circle corresponds to a central angle of 6° and thus is $1/60$ of the inner circumference